# loop stop execution When no of function being added

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have small Piece of code . Here i am checking if button pressed goto specific function on lcd screen like edit display etc. Problem i am facing, I am calling these two function loop alone it working fine. Then i enable all my other function one by one then My serial monitor and lcd screen stop executing.

Below code is working fine.

```
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("enter the loop");
    check_key();
    Display_LCD();
    print_result();
    Serial.println("End of loop");
}
```

Now i changed it to

```
void loop()
{
    Serial.println("enter the loop");
    check_key();
    Display_LCD();
    print_result();
    track_loop(); // involve mathematical equation i.e sun path algorithm
    Serial.println("End of loop");
}
```

here it always printing `enter the loop` and Lcd stop displaying time.

Comment: From your description I understood that the program never returns from `track_loop`. If so, the problem is inside the `track_loop` function.

Answer (score 0):

Does "always printing enter the loop" mean, it prints "enter the loop" several times?
If that is the case, then track_loop() is probably calling loop()

If it prints "enter the loop" only once, track_loop() probably does not return.